# Javascript Countdown Seconds Skip As I Add More Than One Timer Inside Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a javascript countdown timer to my page but i would like to add more than one timer inside my page. when i add more timers the seconds counter start to skip.

here's my markup code

```
<div class="fa countdown-timer" style="font-size: x-large">
    <span class="fa hrRemaining"></span>:<span class="minRemaining"></span>:<span class="secRemaining"></span>
</div>
<div class="fa countdown-timer" style="font-size: x-large">
    <span class="fa hrRemaining"></span>:<span class="minRemaining"></span>:<span class="secRemaining"></span>
</div>
<div class="fa countdown-timer" style="font-size: x-large">
    <span class="fa hrRemaining"></span>:<span class="minRemaining"></span>:<span class="secRemaining"></span>
</div>
```

here's my javascrpit timer

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var remSeconds = Math.floor(@timeRemaining);
        var secondsCounter = Math.floor(remSeconds % 60);
        var minutesCounter = Math.floor((remSeconds / 60) % 60);
        var hoursCounter = Math.floor((remSeconds / 3600));

        function formatNumber(number) {
            if (number < 10)
                return '0' + number;
            else
                return '' + number;
        }

        function startTimers() {
            var $timers = $('.countdown-timer');

            // See https://api.jquery.com/each/
            $timers.each(function() {
                // `this` is the current `.countdown-timer` being iterated by jQuery.each()
                var $timer = $(this);

                var $seconds = $timer.find('.secRemaining');
                var $minutes = $timer.find('.minRemaining');
                var $hours = $timer.find('.hrRemaining');

                $seconds.text(formatNumber(secondsCounter));
                $minutes.text(formatNumber(minutesCounter));
                $hours.text(formatNumber(hoursCounter));

                var _tick = setInterval(function() {
                        if ((remSeconds) > 0) {
                            if (hoursCounter > 0) {
                                if (minutesCounter == 0) {
                                    minutesCounter = 60;
                                    hoursCounter = hoursCounter - 1;
                                }
                            }
                            if (secondsCounter == 0) {
                                secondsCounter = 60;
                                minutesCounter = minutesCounter - 1;
                            }
                            secondsCounter = secondsCounter - 1;
                            remSeconds = remSeconds - 1;

                            $seconds.text(formatNumber(secondsCounter));
                            $minutes.text(formatNumber(minutesCounter));
                            $hours.text(formatNumber(hoursCounter));
                        } else {
                            clearInterval(_tick);
                            document.getElementById("tRemaining").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
                        }
                    },
                    1000);
            })
        }

        startTimers();
</script>
```

the seconds it skips is directly related to the number of timers i add to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sharing these variables

```
        var remSeconds = Math.floor(@timeRemaining);
        var secondsCounter = Math.floor(remSeconds % 60);
        var minutesCounter = Math.floor((remSeconds / 60) % 60);
        var hoursCounter = Math.floor((remSeconds / 3600));
```

across all the timers. Move the declarations inside this

```
            $timers.each(function() {
```

function's scope.